# How to implement batch processing in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, batch-processing

I have a Grails application which implement multiple datasource and its task to process and save excel data(xlsx type) in corresponding datasource tables. But I got a problem when excel file contains huge data and it taken more time to save. So I have used SQL and insert values through batch and it works fine and taken least time to save values but it save values into common datasource tables. So again I have a problem how we use in multiple datasource.

This is working fine but how can we use in multiple datasource. I am describing our query -

```
def dataSource      
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)        
sql.withBatch { stmt ->
    stmt.addBatch("INSERT INTO TableName(Fields...) values(.......)
    stmt.executeBatch() 
}
```

I do not want to implement it through list because it taken approximately same time to save i.e.

```
def dataSourceName = 'lookup'     
List list= []
(0..10000).each{
    Domain dom = new Domain('some property associated with domain class')
    batch.add(dom)
    if(list.size()>1000){ 
        for(Domain object in list){
            object."$dataSourceName".save()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a batch processing framework like Spring Batch. It works quite well in conjunction with Grails and Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite different from the original question, so if I understand it properly, you need to load different information into tables accessed through  different dataSources. You have multiple dataSources defined in your project.
And you want to use groovy.sql.Sql with these dataSources.

All your dataSources are available in your grails application context through dataSource_dataSourceName, so it is as easy as injecting the dataSource and creating the Sql object in avery similar manner as your first code snippet:

```
def dataSource_lookup
def dataSource_otherName

static transactional=false

def doWork() {
  def sql=new Sql(dataSource_lookup)
}
```

Be aware that to be able to be transactional over different dataSources, you need to put XA transactions in place.

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources

Comment: I am written my code in service and when I have checked, it does not looks to works  as transactional. How can we make it transactional = true.I am also checked with "static transactional=true" but it does not.

Comment: You can't without an XA transaction manager.  You are talking to 2 different databases.

Comment: But at a time I am using only one connection i.e. saving value to multiple tables of an database at a time. So this is also a case to use XA transaction manager. Please confirm it.

Comment: If you are using 2 datasources you are using different connection pools

Answer (score 2):

There is an article by Ted Naleid that describes his journey to improving Batch performance in GORM dramatically. It's an old article but it may be worth trying, seeing the impressive performance gain.

http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql

Basically what changes everything in grails, is adding the following in your service: (from Ted Naleid's article because your question is not clear at all about what you are trying to do, you only say what you don't want to do)

```
class BookService {
    def sessionFactory
    def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP

    def importBooksInLibrary(library) {
        library.eachWithIndex { Map bookValueMap, index ->
            updateOrInsertBook(bookValueMap)
            if (index % 100 == 0) cleanUpGorm()
        }
    }    

    def cleanUpGorm() {
        def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
        session.flush()
        session.clear()
        propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
    }

    def updateOrInsertBook(Map bookValueMap) {
        // ... same as above
    }
}
```

the GORM cleanup every x lines makes the batch job scale linearly

Comment: I think when using [`withStatelessSession`](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#_stateless_domain_classes) we don't need the above approach.